# How to call class inside another class in css or scss

Tags: css

I am trying to call a class inside another class. But not working. How to do it?

HTML:

```html
<div class="main">Content</div>
<div class="cover">Cover content</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.main {
    width:100%;
    height:360px;
}

.cover {
    width:90%;
    height:200px;
}

.main:focus {
    .cover {
        margin-left:12px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please pay attention to the answer I give you, so you can learn this topic once and for all. In your HTML, main and cover are adjacent, so you need to use the "+" character to affect them. This means your original code should be sufficient as follows:

```css
.main:hover + .cover {
    color: red
}
```

In addition, you can also use nesting in pure CSS. Pay attention to the following example:

```css
.main:hover {
    & + .cover {
        color: red
    }
}
```

Click on the run code snippet below to see the output code

"Note that I used hover instead of focus to help you better understand and see the output."

```css
.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.cover {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100px;
}

.main:hover + .cover {
    color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="main">Content</div>
<div class="cover">Cover content</div>
```

Comment: Please don't talk to people using an opening line like that. It is unnecessary, demeaning and not very nice. We're all here to learn and/or help.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do this, if you want class cover to be applied on main focus you can use one of these instead:

if cover is a direct child of main:

```
.main:focus>.cover {}
```

if cover is a sibling of main:

```
.main:focus~.cover {}
```

or

```
.main:focus+.cover {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In css you can not nest styles, but in sass or less you can. In pure css you should write css this way:

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="cover">Cover content</div>
    Content
</div>
```

```css
.main:focus .cover{
    margin-left:12px;
}
```

Comment: Your concept not working.

Comment: is element with  class "cover" inside element with class "main" in your html ?

Comment: How to achive using scss?

Comment: I think the problem is not related to nested syntax if my answer css didnt work. to find out if css works or not please replace focus with hover. focus is a little more complicated.

Comment: The most uptodate browsers do support nesting in CSS but it is very recent, especially on Firefox. Plus note that the two divs are siblings, one is not nested inside the other.